# Is $a(a+1)=b(b-1) \implies b = a + 1$ correct? ($a, b > 0$)

Tags: abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics

I've seen a website wrote: $$a(a+1)=b(b-1) \implies b = a + 1$$
I don't know where the second part come from. How to prove it?

Comment: What if $a=b=0$? Also, which website?

Comment: given $a,$  the quadratic formula says that either $b=a+1$ or $b=-a$  because $$ b= \frac{1 \pm (2a+1)}{2} $$

Comment: @player3236 http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/87873. In the solution of D problem.

Comment: In that case, since we must have $a,b > 0$, the case $b=-a$ is rejected. So $b=a+1$ is the only possibility. This demonstrates the important of **context** in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $n = b - a$.  Then your equation becomes
$$a(a + 1) = (a + n)(a + n - 1).$$
After expanding this you can cancel an $a^2$ term from each side, then move everything to one side and it factors giving
$$0 = (2a + n)(n - 1).$$
Thus either $n = 1$ or $n = -2a$, so either $b = a + 1$ or $b = -a$.